# Networking Between Computers on Firewalled Wifi

Tags: networking

I've got three devices that I'd like to network together (printer, a mac and a Windows machine). The mac and Windows machine both have WiFi, however they are connected to a network with no local access (e.g. I can't access a web server on my Windows PC on my Mac). Is there anyway to somehow network these three devices together over ethernet, while maintaining their WiFi connections?

I'm happy to get a router, or switch, but I'm just wondering whether this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, just get a switch, connect the three devices and assign them IP addresses from a range that is clearly different from the Wi-Fi range.

(For example, if the Wi-Fi network uses 192.168.1.0/24, then you could use 192.168.7.0/24, but it'll be even safer to use 172.16.x.0/24 or such.)

Once you do this, "firewalled Wi-Fi" won't be a factor at all; telling the computer to connect to the printer's Ethernet IP address will just go over Ethernet.

(A router would also work, although you don't need any of the "routing" functions *at all* – the only feature you'd be using from it is its built-in DHCP server for automatic IP assignment. Most home 'routers' also come with even more things you don't need, like Wi-Fi that you'd have to disable.)